# Weeks rolling up to months in SQL (date_trunc)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a MODE Case Study which can be accessed here https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/a-drop-in-user-engagement/#the-problem.

I am trying to access Table 2: Events which has a date column 'occurred_at'. I wanted to check the time frame of this case study, that is weeks and months.
I wrote a simple query

```
select distinct(date_trunc('week', occurred_at)) as week, date_trunc('month', occurred_at) as month
from tutorial.yammer_events 
where event_type = 'engagement'
order by week;
```

and to my surprise, the first week of '2014-04-28' showed the month 'May' instead of 'April.
[image]

Can someone please tell me what is the reason for this?
Thank you

Comment: I am unclear on your question.  The beginning of a week can be in the previous month.  This is not surprising.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Running in v13 date_trunc('month', date '2014-04-28) produced 2014-04-01. I can understand your confusing but there must be something else going on.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: If I try to find the month of '2014-04-28; in excel as 'month(2014-04-28)' it comes as April. Ideally, SQL should follow the same thing. Isn't it? Am I missing anything here? And you are right, it can be a previous month, but here it is the following month.

Answer (score 1):

The `PostgreSQL` `date_trunc` rolls up the date to the first instance of the date depending upon the granularity (`day`, `week`, `month`, etc.)

For month this instance is the first day of month i.e. Day 1.
For week this instance is the first day of week i.e. Monday.

Suppose the date is `4th July 2021` which is Sunday, then the `date_trunc` will result in `1st July 2021` for month and `28th June 2021` for week which is Monday inside that week.

Suppose the date is `5th July 2021` which is Monday itself, then the `date_trunc` will still result in `1st July 2021` for month but result in `5th July 2021` for week since it is already Monday.